# undefined method `request_uri' ActionDispatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to create a mobile version of my website

i want when someone visit my site from mobile device it will redirect him to a subdomain m.mywebsite.com

but there is a choice to go to the full site that is stored in cookies

here is my config

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :set_mobile_preferences
  before_filter :redirect_to_mobile_if_applicable
  before_filter :prepend_view_path_if_mobile

  private

    def not_authenticated
      flash[:warning] = 'You have to authenticate to access this page.'
      redirect_to login_path
    end

    def expirated_reset_token
      redirect_to root_path
    end

  # mobile subdomain 
    def set_mobile_preferences
        if params[:mobile_site]
          cookies.delete(:prefer_full_site)
        elsif params[:full_site]
          cookies.permanent[:prefer_full_site] = 1
          redirect_to_full_site if mobile_request?
        end
    end

    def prepend_view_path_if_mobile
        if mobile_request?
          prepend_view_path Rails.root + 'app' + 'mobile_views'
        end
    end

    def redirect_to_full_site
        redirect_to request.protocol + request.host_with_port.gsub(/^m\./, '') +
                    request.request_uri and return
    end

    def redirect_to_mobile_if_applicable
        unless mobile_request? || cookies[:prefer_full_site] || !mobile_browser?
          redirect_to request.protocol + "m." + request.host_with_port.gsub(/^www\./, '') +
                      request.request_uri and return
        end
    end

    def mobile_request?
        request.subdomains.first == 'm'
    end

    helper_method :mobile_request?

    def mobile_browser?
        request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] && request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"][/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android)/]
      end
    helper_method :mobile_browser?

end
```

the problem is when i visit

```
http://m.mywebsite.com/?full_site=1
```

it give me

```
undefined method `request_uri' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x007fdb60fa8a00> Did you mean? request_parameters
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

ActionDispatch request does not, indeed, implement or respond to method `request_uri`.

It has many other methods, though. One of them surely will return what you want (whatever that is). Here's link to documentation for your perusal: [ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html).